# Flying through Dubai to the Seychelles with vape liquid

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, drugs, prohibited-items, seychelles

Very shortly I am going on holiday to the Seychelles. I am flying from the UK via Fly Emirates, changing at Dubai and flying on to the Seychelles.

We are staying with a family who have ordered a considerable supply of vaping products to our house in the UK and requested we bring it over with us (cheaper this way and they get the products they want).

I've read so much conflicting stuff online that it got me nervous.

My question is: will I have any problems flying with the vape stuff - obviously I don't want to get in any trouble. To be clear, it's just nicotine salts etc, no CBD or anything more 'interesting'.

Will I get in trouble in Dubai? Will I get in trouble at Seychelles customs?
Is there a limit on how much I can bring?

There appears to be two vapes, presumably due to their lithium batteries I'll need to bring them in carry on luggage.

Thanks.